# Разное имя пути при каждой итерации

Tags: php

Цикл выводит 9 блоков, а в каждом из этих блоков есть по 9 изображений. Вопрос:

В цикле по выводу изображений, как сделать разные имена пути (src) при каждом выводе картинки.

Например, чтобы **имя src =** с каждым разом увеличивалось на + 1,

**то есть от 1 до 81 .**

Например: 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg, 3.jpeg ,4.jpeg ... 10.jpeg ,11.jpeg ,12.jpeg ... 54.jpeg 55.jpeg и тд.

```js
<?php 

for($a = 1; $a < 10; $a++){
echo "<div class = 'parent_block'>";

for($b = 1; $b < 10; $b++){
echo "<img class ='child_img' src='1.jpeg'>";
}

echo "</div>";
}

?>
```

```css
.parent_block{
margin-top:3%;
margin-left:2%;
margin-bottom:4%;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 10%);
gap:1%;
}


.child_img{
width:100%; 
}
```

Comment: Инициальзируй $count где вне for и инкреметируй его echo `"<img class ='child_img' src='" . $count . ".jpeg'>";$count++;`

Comment: Создать еще один цикл?

Comment: эмм... почему ещё один цикл?

Comment: Не могли бы вы пожалуйста показать код с count, если вам не тяжело)))

Comment: В первом комментарии уже написано.

Comment: `echo "<img class ='child_img' src='".str($b).".jpeg'>";`

Comment: я уже делал так, там будет от 1 до 9 в каждом блоке. а мне нужно чтобы было продолжение от 1 до 81 во всех блоках.

Comment: А где count прописать команду, что нужно считать строго до 81 ?

Comment: второй фор вставь в первый

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = 1;
for($a = 1; $a < 10; $a++){
    echo "<div class = 'parent_block'>";

    for($b = 1; $b < 10; $b++){
        echo "<img class ='child_img' src='$count.jpeg'>";
        $count++;
    }

    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Вот это чудеса, а как это работает? Не могли бы вы пожалуйста объяснить принцип работы сие счетчика "count"

Comment: Что значит - работает? Счетчик увеличивается на единицу каждый раз, когда выполняется строчка `$count++`. Выполняется она 9 * 9 = 81 раз.

Comment: А почему когда я помещаю count++ перед  echo "<img class ='child_img' src='$count.jpeg'>"; то подсчет идет от 2 до 82. С чем это связано?

Comment: А подумать если самому?

Comment: Не знаю, я давно заметил эту странность, но так и не могу понять =(

Comment: Какую странность? Что если счетчик увеличить до вывода - он увеличится?

Comment: Все понял, что-то я жестко тупанул. Я забыл как работает интерпретатор =)

Comment: У меня в html цифры от count выводятся в виде строки.  Возможно ли в строке "div" в echo вывести число(int) ?

Comment: И как ты это представляешь?

Comment: Значит это невозможно?

Comment: Что значит "вывести число int"? Что ты под этим понимаешь?

Comment: целое число в моём случае от 1 до 81